# dbt - where is command line options explained?

Tags: dbt

`dbt run` command has apparently `--target` option as in [Create -t flag as alias for dbt run --target #1281](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues/1281).

I looked for the dbt documents but cannot find about the `--target` option explained.

- [Commands - Syntax overview](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/node-selection/syntax)
- [dbt - run](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/commands/run)

Please advise where to look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With many CLIs, the most up-to-date docs are usually going to be from the CLI itself, using the `--help` option.

To get an overview of dbt and view all sub-commands:

```bash
$ dbt --help
```

To get more info on the options available for each sub-command (e.g., `dbt run`):

```bash
$ dbt run --help
```

I do agree that the web docs should be more complete!